# How to Connect TL-WN725N WiFi Adapter to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, 14.04, drivers, usb

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my computer, and I'm having trouble connecting my TL-WN725N WiFi adapter. When I plug in the adapter, it is not automatically detected or working. I need assistance on how to make it recognized and use it without any issues.

Could someone please provide me with instructions and suggestions on how to get my adapter working smoothly in Ubuntu? I don't know the steps to follow and would greatly appreciate help from someone who has experience in this matter.

Please share the necessary steps and any recommendations below to help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Computer Information:

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
WiFi Adapter: TL-WN725N
```

Comment: You could try installing drivers from this GitHub repo: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Now, I am facing a new challenge with enabling monitor mode. When I enter the command "iwconfig" in the terminal, I notice that my USB device is not being detected. As a result, I am unable to proceed with enabling monitor mode for my wireless network adapter.

Comment: @KamiKaramazov, I posted steps from my recreation of Kali Linux instructions from the source page.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed steps for Kali Linux from https://nooblinux.com/how-to-enable-monitor-mode-on-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3/ on Xubuntu 22.04.

`sudo iwconfig` returns:

```
wlx3460f9macadr  IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

---

For reference here are the *altered* steps from link above:

- Good old apt update.

```
sudo apt update;
#  sudo apt upgrade; # should not be necessary
#  sudo apt install bc; # Not sure if calculator is necessary
sudo apt install aircrack-ng; # Not installed by default on Ubuntu 22.04
```

- To compile wifi driver:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r);
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus;
cd rtl8188eus;
```

- Having downloaded everything necessary, your wireless connection could be cut after this command.
- Disable default *driver*.

```
sudo rmmod r8188eu.ko # gets rid of default 'driver';
sudo bash -c 'echo "blacklist r8188eu" > "/etc/modprobe.d/tl-wn725n-v3.conf"';
# reboot; # Not necessary
```

- Install downloaded mod.

```
make;
sudo make install;
sudo modprobe 8188eu; # Notice that, default one has a leading 'r'
```

- Find out the wireless adapter's name, was `wlxMMMMMMMMMMMM`in my case, where `3460f9macadr` is physical/MAC address (34:60:f9:MA:CA:DR, reducted) of the USB wifi adapter.

```
ip a;
```

- Put interface down and back up in monitor mode. Will disconnect from other wireless network adapters as well unfortunately.

```
sudo ifconfig wlx3460f9macadr down;
sudo airmon-ng check kill;
sudo iwconfig wlx3460f9macadr mode monitor;
sudo ifconfig wlx3460f9macadr up;
sudo iwconfig;
```

- I had to restart NetworkManager to get my notification panel wifi symbol back on Xubuntu.

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager;
```

I haven't used monitor mode before, so will take iwconfig's word for monitor mode being enabled. Comments to actually confirm that would be appreciated.